# React JS: Reusable and modifiable ui components?

Tags: reactjs, components, frontend, antd

I just started working on a project and I decided to use ant design package. I want to create reusable and modifiable components. For instance, I want to create a button component and use it in entire app instead of using antd's button component directly. Therefore, if I decided to change how the button looks I will just change button component I created. So if I decided to use another ui package I just need to change button component or style of it instead of changing it in entire app. I am actually a back-end developer and do not have much knowledge on front-end. I wanna know if my approach is proper or not. I am asking because bellow code does not seem proper to me:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';


function myButton(props) {
  return (
    <Button {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
}

export default myButton;
```

In other files:

```
import { Button } from './components/button';
```

Instead of:

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
```

Should I use this approach in that way or extend these components without a change (or export them directly from components directory)?

Comment: That's fine as it is.

Comment: i think, it's a correct way except, you need to change the way of importing it should be `import Button from './components/button';` **default import** and **named import**.

Comment: ...and it looks like you're doing props.children twice. (once from the spread operator and once by inserting them as actual children).